# Python3 ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter'

Tags: python-3.x, counter, importerror

I've been trying to run this code in python3:

```
from collections import Counter
a = "aaaaabbbbccc"
counter = Counter(a)
print(counter)
```

but it throws the

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter'

Only solution I've found online is that Counter works only in python3... well not in this case.
I'm running it on:

- Linux Mint 19.3
- Python 3.6.9

Any possible solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a file called `collections.py` in your working directory? Run `import collections; print(collections.__file__)` to find out why it isn't the module from the standard library.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I've renamed it and now it works as it should. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The cause was a file in working directory named collections.py
After I've renamed it, the import worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you should rename your file to something other than collections.py, such as my_collections.py. Then, in your code, you can import the Counter class from the built-in collections module like this:

```
from collections import Counter
```